# white stuff on olive tree leaves

Tags: olive

I bought an olive tree a year ago and it is growing nicely since then. I keep it indoors in winter months, as the climate where I live would be too cold for it. In summer I move it to my balcony. 
Since several months, I see some tiny white featherlike stuff on many leaves. And also some sticky white stuff too. [image]

what causes this and what must I do to get rid of them?

Comment: It looks like there are some standard aphids there. Sticky stuff would be the "honeydew" that they excrete. I don't know if this is related to feather stuff, but a number of molds and fungi thrive on this honeydew. You might have Wooly Aphids, which DO look like feathery stuff.